# Unity security at user data stored locally vs server-side

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 1-vs-1 game in which the client will only reserve a socket when matchmaking and during gameplay.

I was wondering if the game-world data should stay server-side, keeping all player information there, and asking with a packet when the information is needed client-side, or if I should have the client-sides send their states to each-other.

Which one will be the more secure, according to the weakness and data hijacking?

Comment: You should never rely on client side validation.

Comment: Attempted to improve readability of the question. Revert or change if my changes are not what you meant to ask...

Comment: And yes, as @SamMarion said, if you want security, you don't rely on client-side for validations. However, since each client has to have their own representation of the game-world to show to the players, there has to be a compromise or an attention to which data you keep on the server, and which you keep on the client. --- Stuff that can be cheated upon like player-position, ammo, health, etc should stay server-side or at least be checked in respect to a server-side validation, but cosmetic stuff can/should stay client-side.

Comment: Network latency and delays between server and client are also an important factor, and the reason why most games implement a structure of keeping game-world data in **both** server and clients; with client-side validations enforcing client-side respect to a specific margin-of-error in regards to the server-side version. This keeps the clients running smoothly and without lag, while also enforcing the game rules (or kicking a player out if his client cannot be enforced or if enforcing the server-side is needed constantly; which is a clear indicator of cheating/hacking).

Comment: This is completely opinion-based question. Depending on a game it is up to you as game developer to decide which option to pick taking security and performance into account. Some consideration already covered in comments, but that information should also be easy to find as it is common knowledge.